# How do I play with friends?

Tags: paladins

In the release of the Paladins game on Steam, I was able to successfully add a player by name to my list of friends, but I could not find a way to play a match with my friend. I clicked on every button I found in the match setup area, but was not successful. I briefly skimmed the Paladins website [forums](http://forums.paladins.com/) and [FAQ](http://www.paladins.com/faq/), but did not locate an answer. How can my friend and I join the same match and play together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on social in the lower right, click the friend you want to party with, and click invite to party. From there, I believe you can just click play and then the gametype of your choice as usual.

Comment: That worked; I had to make sure my friend was not in casual looking for a game at the same time I was.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)